# creating an angelscript asSMethodPtr (without the asMETHOD macro)

Tags: c++, templates, angelscript

I'm trying to get a more dynamic workflow with Angelscript happening, where I don't rely on the asMETHOD macro to pass class/method information to Angelscript.

However, I'm unable to get it to work so far.

Here's some structs I've defined (with which to setup Class and Method data):

```
struct Class {
std::string name;
std::string factorySignature;
void* pointer;
void* factoryPointer;
void* addRefMethodPointer;
void* releaseRefMethodPointer;
};


struct Method {
std::string name;
std::string signature;
void* pointer;
};
```

Later on, I try to create an `asSMethodPtr` struct object using a Class struct object I had created earlier.  This is what I do:

```
auto methodPtr = asSMethodPtr<sizeof(void (classObject.pointer)())>::Convert((void (classObject.pointer)())(classObject.addRefMethodPointer));
```

Unfortunately, this results in the following errors:

```
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp:98:66: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp:98:68: error: template argument 1 is invalid
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp:98:107: error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
src/common/as_wrapper/AngelScript.cpp:98:142: error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘<expression error>’
```

Anyone have any ideas?  I've afraid this asSMethodPtr struct is pushing the limits of my C++ abilities...

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to member functions have the format of *return_type* (*class_name*::*)(*parameter_list*) *const-volatile_qualifiers*. The argument you are trying pass to `sizeof` is composed of what looks like a local variable and a member variable and is ill-formed. It should look like the following

```
sizeof(void (Class::*)())
```

The argument you are passing to `Convert` is also ill-formed. You need to take the member function by address using the `&` address-of operator. Another problem is that `addRefMethodPointer` is a member variable not a function so the cast will fail.

```
struct Class
{
    void SomeMemberFunction() {}
};

(void (Class::*)())(&Class::SomeMemberfunction)
```